# JSF,CSS - dynamically decrease brightness

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I'm playing with CSS styles. how to make this somehow intelligently?

[image]

I'm able to create manually x variation of green color in css file, but it mustn't be a solution..

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date1}" styleClass="green1"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date2}" styleClass="green2"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date3}" styleClass="green3"/>
```

How to decrease it "dynamically"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume when you say *"dynamically"* you mean *"somehow programmatically, without having to manually maintain different CSS classes"*. If so, your scenario is fairly straightforward - you could have all your output have the same color, but different opacity. You should be able to directly set `style` attribute:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date1}" style="opacity:1"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date2}" style="opacity:0.8"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date3}" style="opacity:0.6"/>
```

~[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/bcL7L/)

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery (many JSF frameworks already use it/include it), you can select all elements with class `MyClass` like that:

```
$(".myClass")
```

Then you can use the `each()` to define a function to execute in all of them, and use `css` in the function to change attributes.

```
$(".myClass").each(function() {
  $this.css("color", "myNewColor");
}
```

Launch this code with a timeout and set the various levels of color.

I have searched but I have found no way of directly editing the CSS style; I do not know if someone can propose a method for it.

UPDATE: [A way of changing the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name); the downside is that it seems that it replaces all the classes and maybe your JSF library is adding some classes by itself, if it is in a component. Use with care.

Comment: Why would it ever be appropriate to push this logic to be executed on the client side? Not only painful to maintain, it's also [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)-ish

Comment: I have read again your question and I had misunderstood it; I thought that you wanted to fade all your text over a span of time (that's why there is a timeout). You can still try with a variation of my soluction (keep "myNewColor" as a global variable, change for each use) but I am not so sure about the order in which the elements will be returned.