# Modifying style for a class of elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript)

I am creating a list of elements in my jsp page with the same class name. Say I am creating 4  elements with same class name as "someName". Now, I want to modify the style of these elements dynamically using javascript.i.e, when a style is changed for the class it should reflect in all the elements referenced by the class name.Also, I have to do this with IE8. Can this be accomplished?

Thanks

Comment: Problem statement is unclear. Can you please post code snippet?

Comment: check this out, it's about changing classes on elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name

Comment: I can't use jQuery. Another big limitation is I have to achieve this using IE8, that too by using plain old javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: YES

Ah you also want to know how? Why haven't you asked for the how?

I give you an example in jQuery

```
$(".someName").css("background-color","green:);
```

That would change the background-color all elements with the class 'someName'

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sven. But, i have to use simple pure javascript without any jQuery thing. That too i have to make it IE8 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to add an additional class to the relevant elements.

Javascript

```
var elements =  document.getElementsByClassName('oldClass');
for(var i = 0;i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].className += ' newClass' //dont forget the first space
}
```

CSS

```
oldClass{color:red;}
newClass{color:white; font-weight:bold;}
```

the jQuery solution is more elegant, but you can do it with plain ol' javascript too.

Comment: getElementsByClassName() doesn't work with IE8. isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

In general, I would do as @sven-bieder suggests, but to answer your specific question: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409250/45948

Comment: You referred the op to an internal link, which in turn refers to an external link....why???

Comment: The internal link is to see the SO question with the according answers. What's the problem with that? Is it the extra click that bothers you?

Comment: Its the fact that your answer adds no value. -1

Comment: I pointed him to a valid answer, so what's your problem? And you're the one to decide if it's added value. Did you know you can change rules or do you know how to do it? I think it is added value.

Comment: Just quit whining. I'm not going to argue over a downvote.