# CSS transition final state

Tags: html, css, transition

how do i make sure that the webpage remains in the final state of the transition? like if a bix box turns from green to red on transition, i would like it to stay red. and not go back to green. How can this be done?

Comment: Basically, with pure CSS transitions you can't. Transitions rely on 'states' like 'hover' so as soon as that state no longer applies the transition reverses. What you really want to do, I suspect, is apply a different default state or class ...and that, essentially, relies on Javascript

Comment: An alternative is a CSS keyframe animation which will start and end over a specific time. Which would be best for you will depend on what precisely it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the class with jQuery and have a transition for the change this way the color will be changed in the html via the added class.

[jquery change class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)