# javascript to change css class, rather than append to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, append

How do I change the below javascript to change my css class, rather than add/append to it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){   
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul#horizontal.nav.menu').addClass('myNewClass');
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to change the following UL:

```
<ul class="nav menu" id="horizontal">
```

to

```
<ul class="myclass" id="horizontal">
```

I have tried the following just before my closing `</body>` tag and not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){   
          $(document).ready(function(){
            // add items for bootstrap dropdown's
              $("#horizontal").attr("class", "myclass");
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
```

Comment: Right in the documentation for removeClass: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: @DhavalMarthak that is what he has now, in a closure to ensure the `$` variable within the function will not conflict with any other library

Comment: Duplicate of [jquery change class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)

Comment: id's are meant to be unique.. no need of making it more narrow by giving classnames like `.nav` or `.menu`. or prefixing with `ul`.. I may be wrong but I don't recommend it. Then you should do like this `document.getElementById('horizontal').className = "myNewClass";`

Comment: I have tried all of these & added script just before my closing </body> tag & they don't work. I am trying to change <ul class="nav menu" id="horizontal"> to <ul class="myclass" id="horizontal">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `attr` method:

```
$('ul#horizontal.nav.menu').attr( 'class', 'myNewClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy..

`$("#mydiv").attr("class", "myclass");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mydiv").prop("class", "myclass");
```

Comment: You should use `className` instead if you use `prop` method and not `attr`.