# change class name of object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I would like to change the class name of a jQuery object.

This is what I have:

```
var container = $('#container');
```

Then in the following function I would like to change the classname to newstate

```
function setstate(newstate) {
    state = newstate;
    //change container.classname to setstate
    currentsate = state;
}
```

I have looked up how to do this and tried the toggleClass and removeClass then addClass methods but neither seem to be working.

Also, in this function I need to get the position right, will these lines work?

```
function init() {
    var temp = container.offset();
    xoffset = temp.left;
    yoffset = temp.top;
    fontsize = container.offsetHeight / 1.5;
    linewidth = container.offsetHeight / 19;

    setstate('intro');
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked [the jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)?

Comment: A duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var container = $('#container');

function changeClass(newClass){

    container.attr('class',newClass);
}


changeClass('myNewClass');
```

This example will erase the existing classes...if you want to add a class use `container.addClass(newClass);`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this:

```
$("selector").toggleClass("a").toggleClass("b");
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/victorrseloy/8cfu6/ to see an example