# Can't change class with className

Tags: javascript

part of function :

```
function __openSettingsPage(addonName, targetItem) {
 $("#prev-selected").className="addons-listitem"; //error
 $("#prev-selected").removeAttr("id");
 targetItem.className="addons-listitem-cursor"; //ok
 targetItem.id="prev-selected";
};
```

part of markup :

```
for (var i in __addons) {
htmlDiv+="<DIV class='addons-listitem'
onclick='__openSettingsPage(\"" + __addons[i] + "\", this);'>
...
```

I need to change background-color of `<div>` with class `addons-listitem` in function when I click on it. But there are many other `<div>` with class `addons-listitem` and previously changed `<div>` which recover its background color when click on another `<div>`. Now, this code is changes all background color and can't able to recover. There must be only one `<div>` which change background at the same time and it's important to change class name because all css styles must be in `var css= "";`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name

Comment: I think you need to use $(this) instead of $(#prev-selected)

Comment: If you are using jQuery, tag it is jQuery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
 $("#prev-selected").addClass("addons-listitem")
```

If you want to remove all class and add a class use

```
 $("#prev-selected").removeClass().addClass("addons-listitem")
```