# how to change class name at run time for particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i need to change the class name at the run time for the particular div and this one is also supports for image preview using JQuery. . .

Comment: I think this will help to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name

Comment: This question was a waste of time for all. Please refer jquery.com or search for jquery cheat sheet and you get it all

Comment: thanks for information Akshay and sorry for waste of your time. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One

```
 $('.button').click(function () {
     $("#Div").attr('class', 'CssName');
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

`$("#YourDivID").attr('class', 'NewClassName');`