# Add active class to nav links with exception for some li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have `ul.menu` for which few `li` are styled differently, therefore those `li`  dont need to add active class.

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li id="1st" class="default"><a href="#">Text1</a></li>
   <li id="2nd" class="default"><a href="#">Text2</a></li>
   <li class="cross-out"><a href="#">Text3</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery to add active class for first two links, except `li.cross-out`

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function(){
    $('ul.menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).not('cross-out').addClass('active');
});
```

What is wrong? Hope I was clear enough...

Comment: `.not('.cross-out')`

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would have shown this to you...

Comment: oh my F@ASD@ sorry for disturbing. nothing meaningful here to see...

Comment: Would it be better to use something like `$(this).siblings('li.active').removeClass('active')` instead of `$('ul.menu li').removeClass('active')`?

Comment: PeterKA, you are right, didnt know of that move. Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The period makes all the difference. Then because you may have several other `ul.menu` elements on your page, you just want the one whose `li` was clicked to change:

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).not('.cross-out').addClass('active');
});
```

```js
$('ul.menu li').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).not('.cross-out').addClass('active');
    });
```

```css
.active {
  background-color:gray;
  font-weight:bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
   <li class="default"><a href="#">Text1</a></li>
   <li class="default"><a href="#">Text2</a></li>
   <li class="cross-out"><a href="#">Text3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu">
   <li class="default"><a href="#">Text1</a></li>
   <li class="default"><a href="#">Text2</a></li>
   <li class="cross-out"><a href="#">Text3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu">
   <li class="default"><a href="#">Text1</a></li>
   <li class="default"><a href="#">Text2</a></li>
   <li class="cross-out"><a href="#">Text3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the class identifier before cross-out:

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function(){
    $('ul.menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).not('.cross-out').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, dsg! But for the community this post should be deleted, since the question is not helpful to others... My mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a toggle class function

```
$("#td_id").toggleClass('default active');
```

related post [jquery change class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)