# Add a only random class from a list when mouse over

Tags: jquery

I have this code to add a class from a list when the mouse is over a button, and it works, but every time the mouse touches the button a new class is added from the list. I need it just add one class.

```
var classes = ["fadeOutRight","fadeOutLeft","fadeOutDown","fadeOutUp","zoomOutLeft","zoomOutRight","zoomOutDown","zoomOutUp"];

$(".work").mouseover(function() {
    $(".paj").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
    });
});
```

I tried this but is not working:

```
var classes = ["fadeOutRight","fadeOutLeft","fadeOutDown","fadeOutUp","zoomOutLeft","zoomOutRight","zoomOutDown","zoomOutUp"];

$(".work").mouseover(function() {
  if(!$(this).hasClass(classes)){
    $(".paj").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
        });
    };
});
```

Also, I need when the mouse is out it deletes all classes from the list. I tried this but it does not work either:

```
$(".work").mouseout(function() {
    $(".paj").removeClass(classes);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution may be helpful

```
 var classes = ["fadeOutRight","fadeOutLeft","fadeOutDown","fadeOutUp","zoomOutLeft","zoomOutRight","zoomOutDown","zoomOutUp"];


var checkclass = false;
$(".work").mouseover(function() {
    if(checkclass==false) {
       $(".paj").each(function(){
         $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
       });
    } else {
        checkclass=true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using addClass

You may use other methods to change the class (given that your element does not have any other class), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name).

Your code could then be:

```
var classes = ["fadeOutRight","fadeOutLeft","fadeOutDown","fadeOutUp","zoomOutLeft","zoomOutRight","zoomOutDown","zoomOutUp"];

$( ".work" ).mouseover( function() {
    $( ".paj" ).each( function(){
        $( this ).attr( 'class', classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)] );
    });
});
```