# Changing class type using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am using this code to fetch the data from startup.php.The response of the PHP file is JSON with 3 fields. One of the field in JSON response is a status message. How to change the value of div class `.content` based on the status message. I need to do that to change the color of the text displayed in the content DIV based on the status message. .content is the class name of the DIV

```
var loadinggif = '../img/loading.gif';
$(document).ready(function(){  
    // set up the click event
        $('body').on('click','.btnbg', function() {
                var toLoad = '../vr/startup.php';
                $('.content').empty();
                $('.content').slideUp('slow', loadContent);
                $('#load').remove();
                $('#waiting').append('<div id="load"><img src="' + loadinggif + '" alt="Loading" /></div>');
                $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
                function loadContent() {

                    var userName = $('#userName').val();                    
                    var remote_addr = $('#remote_addr').val(); 
                    var forwarded_for = $('#forwarded_for').val();
                    var url = $('#url').val();
                    //$('#forwarded_for1').val()'';
  var _post = {'userName': userName, 'ipAddr1':remote_addr,'ipAddr2':forwarded_for, 'url':url};

   $('.content').load(toLoad, _post , function(response, status, xhr) 


if (status == 'error') {
                        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                        $(".content").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }            
            }).slideDown('slow', hideLoader());
                }
                function hideLoader() {
                        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
                }
                return false;
        });
```

Comment: Use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` to change an elements class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery change class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `css()` function in Jquery :

```
$(".content").css({'background-color': 'red'});
```

### Edit

I red your question wrong. To change class you can use `$('.content').removeClass('classOne').addClass('classTwo');`

If you have a class like `has-error`, you can use `toggleClass()` to toggle it, it will remove it if it's present or add it if not : 
`$('.content').toggleClass('has-error');`

for your `if else`probleme, simply do :

```
if(condition) {
   $('.content').removeClass('class2 class3').addClass('class1');
} else if(condition2) {
   $('.content').removeClass('class1 class3').addClass('class2');
} else {
   $('.content').removeClass('class1 class2').addClass('class3');
}
```

Comment: Based on the response how do i add a if condition ?

Comment: Depending on how many condition you have, you could use a `? : ;` operator , or you could simply use a `if else` and set the correct class in the correct condition

Comment: How to parse a Json ?

Comment: @gurudev265 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript

Comment: @gurudev265 you can use `JSON.parse()`, it will become an object or an array depending on your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeClass()` and `addClass()`.

Here is an example:

```
$('.content').removeClass("styleOne").addClass("styleTwo");
```

Edit

```
if(response == "Worked Fine"){ 
    $('.content').removeClass("default").addClass("styleGreen");
}else{
     $('.content').removeClass("default").addClass("styleRed");
}
```

Comment: How do i add a IF condition ? Based on response

Comment: If it's true = Green or else Red