# Item Active for Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have made a navigational bar in Bootstrap.

It is in a file called `header.html`.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
       <li class="item active"><a href="./index.shtml">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="./courses.shtml">Courses</a></li>
       <li><a href="./projects.shtml">Projects</a></li>
       <li><a href="./publications.shtml">Publications</a></li>
       <li><a href="./patents.shtml">Patents</a></li>
   </ul>
```

I use an `include virtual` on all 5 pages on the navbar to display my menu bar.

```
<!--#include virtual="/templates/header.html" -->
```

I am trying to figure out a way to apply the "item active" class to the page that the browser is viewing, all while using an included header file.

The only solution I thought of would be creating a CSS sheet per page, and only loading that specific CSS sheet depending on the page loaded.

That specific CSS sheet would style that specific `li` item.

I am open to using JavaScript if needed.

Comment: I am not totally clear on what you are trying to do but if I have it right then JS (or more likely jQuery) to modify the DOM based on the loaded page seems to be the direction you might want to head in, maybe.

Comment: You can set the active class by PHP or JS by looking at the URL

Comment: @jwpfox If I know that the url ends "courses" and "projects" like in my example, how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name for one piece of the puzzle

Comment: @jwpfox Solved. Thanks a lot! I used this from the link you sent: $("#td_id").addClass('newClass');
I just change the ID to the ID of the navbar menu block that I want selected, and change the newClass to "item active".