# can't change "class" by using attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var allp = $("div p");
for (var i = 0; i < allp.length; i++) {
  allp.attr("class", function(i, n) {
    n += 1;
    return n;
  });
  console.log(allp[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://lib.sinaapp.com/js/jquery/2.0.2/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="1">1</p>
  <p class="2">2</p>
  <p class="3">3</p>
  <p class="4">4</p>
  <p class="5">5</p>
</div>
```

`i` means index, `n`  means the current value of "class". Just wanted to make each classname +1,but failed to do that.And  the console.log is :

```
<p class="11111">1</p>  
<p class="21111">2</p>  
<p class="31111">3</p>      
<p class="41111">4</p>  
<p class="51111">5</p>
```

**Expected output**:

```
    <p class="2">1</p>  
    <p class="3">2</p>  
    <p class="4">3</p>      
    <p class="5">4</p>  
    <p class="6">5</p>
```

Comment: Check this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)

Comment: That's not the result I'm seeing: https://jsfiddle.net/4f7oh2ja/

Comment: I assume the `console.log` isn’t exactly like that and you want `return Number(n) + 1;` with no `n += 1` and no loop?

Comment: @David Check the console

Comment: @HenslerSoftware: I did.  Did *you*?

Comment: @David class is being returned as <p class="111111">1</p> but still not what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @HenslerSoftware: It may not be what the OP is looking for, but it's also not what the OP claims to be the current output.  Observe the output in the console, and observe the output in the question above.  Look really closely.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vpgfckx6/

Comment: @user10968312 Can you add the expected output ?

Comment: I made some mistakes in the post (the output) and I have corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply ignore `for` loop:

```js
var allp=$("div p");    
allp.attr("class",(i,n)=>Number(n)+1);
console.log(allp)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>       
  <p class="1">1</p>    
  <p class="2">2</p>    
  <p class="3">3</p>        
  <p class="4">4</p>    
  <p class="5">5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: the for loop here is unnecessary?

Comment: @user10968312 You can do it by `for` loop, but it's more simple without it. Additionally, if you make a loop and pass a function to `.attr()`, then your code will be processed multiple.

Comment: But if I dont use for loop ,what will the i mean here?It should be index when using for loop

Comment: @user10968312 `i` is passed to the function that processes the 'reclassing'. [It's the index](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function), but it isn't used in this example.

Comment: By passing i and n without for  loop, the function can still operate each p's classname,right?

Comment: @user10968312 Yes, if you pass a function to `.attr()`, it will *loop over* each element as a `for` loop do, but this way is more simple to read and use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
var allp = $("div p");
for (var i = 0; i < allp.length; i++) {
    allp.attr("class", function (i, n) {
        const n2 = Number(n) + 1;
        return n2;
    });
    console.log(allp[i]);
}
```

Comment: So I didn't make n be a number?

Comment: No, in your code 'n' is a string, and instead of adding you are concatenating

Comment: Thanks,you are right.But bacause of the implicit iteration of jQuery,here the for loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate through each element in `$allp`, then [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the new class name.

```js
var $allp = $("div p")

$.each($allp, (index, el) => {
  const $newEl = $(el).attr('class', `newClass-${index + 2}`)
  console.log($newEl[0])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>       
  <p class="1">1</p>    
  <p class="2">2</p>    
  <p class="3">3</p>        
  <p class="4">4</p>    
  <p class="5">5</p>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/xMZqYP)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the class attribute value of each p element increment it after converting it to a Number and then assign this value to the same element as the new text value.

```js
var allp=$("div p");    
for(var i=0;i<allp.length;i++){     
  $(allp[i]).text(Number($(allp[i]).attr("class")) + 1);
console.log(allp[i]);   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://lib.sinaapp.com/js/jquery/2.0.2/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<div>       
  <p class="1">1</p>    
  <p class="2">2</p>    
  <p class="3">3</p>        
  <p class="4">4</p>    
  <p class="5">5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to post the expected output before.I mean changing the classname instead of changing the content of p

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery. Get the class, parse it to int and increment. It'll throw an error if you have none numeric characters in your class though so may want to do a check `!isNaN`.

```
$('div p').each(function(){
    console.log(parseInt($(this).attr('class')) + 1);
});
```