# I want to change the class from changing text

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble making the class change depending on text that changes automatically.

```
<div class="WAIT">
    <p id="device_display">WAIT</p>
</div>
```

The text changes to WAIT, ON, OFF.

NOTE: The text changes automatically using MQTT.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you change your text?

Comment: @Chaska It changes using MQTT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class `.parent` and try these scripts:

```js
$('#device_display').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  $(this).closest('.parent')
    .removeClass('WAIT ON OFF')
    .addClass($(this).text());
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
  $('#device_display').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent WAIT">
    <p id="device_display">WAIT</p>
</div>

<hr>
<input type="text">
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class called `changeText` and use that to update the values.

jQuery:

```
$(".changeText").attr('class', $(".changeText").innerHTML+' changeText');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="WAIT changeText">
    <p id="device_display">WAIT</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I need something like "If (text = WAIT) then (Class = WAIT)".

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="WAIT" id="changeid">
   <p id="device_display">WAIT</p>
</div>

var htmltxt = $("#device_display").html();
$("#changeid").attr('class', htmltxt);
```

Not sure if this is what you looking for, this is the possible answer I can give based on my knowledge.

Links to refer:

[J-Query change class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name/3452795)

[J-Query .html documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)