# Chrome console, checkbox

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to use the console to checkbox in chrome. I already use different way but it not work

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
// or
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, max = allInputs.length; i < max; i++){
    if (allInputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
        allInputs[i].checked = true;
}
```

[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcNC0.png)

I just realize that to change it, I have to change the name of the class "icheckbox_minimal" to "icheckbox_minimal checked"

Please help me

Comment: Your question is quite incomplete. Please describe more.

Comment: so how can I tick to the box, is there anyway to change the name of the class ? I already try this one but it not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name/3452795

Comment: the html code is on a picture

Comment: Looks like a customized checkbox control so you probably need to [dispatch a 'change' event](/a/41981710).